# Ionic3 app crash while choose images from gallery

Tags: ionic3

I am using image picker plugin to take image form gallery. so if user take picture camera first and then get a picture using gallery then it works fine.

But if user comes and choose direct gallery without (using camera) then app crashes without any error.

```
 //Get options on device if camera or gallery
  presentActionSheet() {
 let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
   title: 'Choose or take a picture',
   buttons: [
  {
    text: 'Take a picture',
    handler: () => {
      this.takePicture();
    }
  },
  {
    text: 'Choose pictures',
    handler: () => {
      this.openImagePicker();
    }
  }
]
 });
actionSheet.present();
 }
```

And function for image picker is here.

```
//Open image picker multiple images
  openImagePicker(){
this.pic = 'undefined';
let options = {
  maximumImagesCount: 1,
}
//initalize readAsArrayBuffer for base64 and images gallery to display on view
this.photos = new Array<string>();
this.base64Data = new Array<string>();
this.imagePicker.getPictures(options)
.then((results) => {
  this.reduceImages(results).then(() => {
    console.log('all images cropped!!');
    for (let index = 0; index < results.length; index++) {
        //here iam converting image data to base64 data and push a data to array value.
        console.log('Seelcted images are');
        //console.log(this.imageSelected);
        this.base64.encodeFile(results[index]).then((base64File: string) => {
        //Create a base64 array for server transfer
        this.base64Data.push(base64File);
  }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

      }
    //console.log("Image Lists", this.photos);
  });
   }, (err) => { console.log(err) });
  }
```

Plugings I am using

```
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { ImagePicker } from '@ionic-native/image-picker';
import { Crop } from '@ionic-native/crop';
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file- 
 transfer';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { Base64 } from '@ionic-native/base64';
```

What's going wrong with this? I am using ionic3

Comment: can you give permission for use gallery?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue and seems like some memory leak.

I then tried the forked version of the Cordova plugin and it works fine.

```
https://github.com/abelabbesnabi/cordova-plugin-image-picker
```